# Grunt: "Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR >> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue."

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I keep getting the error:

"borted due to warnings.
  S C:\atomworkspace\angularproject\conFusion> grunt
  oading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>     arning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
>     "

I wish Grunt could point me to the line number in the gruntfile where the syntax error occurs. Quite frankly this should have come with the package by default. Seems pretty common sense to me. Anyways here is my code. I can't find where the issue is. Someone please help.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {
//time how long the tasks take.
require('time-grunt')(grunt);
//automatically load required grunt tasks
require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin'
});
// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    //Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: {
            src: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                'app/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        }
    }
    copy: {
        dist: {
            cwd: 'app',
            src: ['**', '!styles/**/*.css', '!scripts/**/*.js'],
            dest: 'dist',
            expand: 'true'
        },
        fonts: {
            files: [{
                //for bootstrap fonts
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
                src: ['fonts/*,*'],
                dest: 'dist'
            }]
        }
    },
    clean: {
        build: {
            src: ['dist/']
        }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
        html: 'app/menu.html'
        options: {
            dest: 'dist'
        }
    },
    //Concat
    concat: {
        options: {
            separator: ';'
        },
        //dist configuration given by useminPrepare
        dist: {}
    },

    //Uglify
    Uglify: {
        //dist configuration given by useminPrepare
        dist: {}
    },

cssmin: {
    dist: {}
},
    //Filerev
    filerev: {
        options: {
            encoding: 'utf8',
            algorithm: 'md5',
            length: 20
        },
        release: {
            //Filerev: release hashes(md5) all assets (images, js, and css)
            // in dist direcftory
            // brackets are used to specify file
            files: [{
                src: [
                    'dist/scripts/*.js',
                    'dist/styles/*.css',
                ]
            }]
        }
    },
    //useminPrepare``
    //Replace all assets with their recent version in html and css files.
    //options.assetDirs holds the directories for finding the assets                         
     usemin: {
        html: ['dist/*.html'],
        css: ['dist/styles/*.css'],
        options: {
            assetDirs: ['dist', 'dist/styles']
        }
    }
});
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean',
    'jshint',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy',
    'filerev',
    'usemin'
]);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['build']);

};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `grunt --verbose` to get more specific error messages.

You are missing a comma before your copy task:

```
},
copy: {
```

and one after your `html:` field in `useminPrepare` task:

```
 useminPrepare: {
        html: 'app/menu.html',
```

Comment: The task names should exactly match. You have used capital U in  '**uglify**' task name. Please change it accordingly.